# How to abstract a static classes

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a static class. I can modify it and make it extends interface\abstract class.

It contains

- lots of readonly and consts members.
- staic methods.

In order to make this code testable, I want to

1. Separate it to DTO and Manager.
2. Abstract each of them. But how to do this as the classes are static?

Comment: You should describe in more detail what you want to do. Can you change the static class?

Comment: Why is your static code *untestable*? It might be difficult to mock/stub it as a dependency in other parts of system, but static members itselves are testable just like anything else.

Comment: Give us some code to illustrate what you want to test. Static classes are no harder to test that any other type, so we are just guessing what your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion there are two things static classes are good for:

1. providing global functions/algorithms (that should not depend on state - a.k.a pure functions)
2. hold global data

If you model the methods in there so that they are pure you can test those right away. Global data (your constants and read-only members) on the other hand don't need to be testet as they should be produced by said methods.

So if your static methods use the global data from your class just refactor them to include this data as parameters into the method, overload those with simple wrappers feeding your global data and test the new - now pure - functions. Take care to include things like database-data or system-times (DateTime.Now) and similar side-effect data into your methods as well.

If the parameterlist gets to big refactor the method into a class where some/most of the parameters are encapsulated into the new classes fields - always remember the S from SOLID (single responsibility) - only clutter everything into a "MyStaticGlobals"-class/singelton if you test the parts in seperation.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to convert over from used a static class to a regular class. In your main application you add a singleton so that the same instance is used from everywhere, so the singletone effectively turns a instance into a global. But in testing you can create an instance on demand.

Comment: If I don't opt for singelton. How to abstarct static fields?

Comment: You cannot abstract a field, you would need to change it into a property.